# Number of rows returns as 0 when retrieving data from cursor

Tags: android, database, exception, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

Below is the code snippet which I'm using:

```
...
final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    People._ID, People.NAME
};
preparePeople();
final Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
android.util.Log.i("TAG","Rowcount =" + **c.getCount()**);
c.moveToFirst();
String s = **c.getString(0)**;
...
private void preparePeople() {
    final ContentResolver mResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    mResolver.delete(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
    final ContentValues valuse = new ContentValues();
    valuse.put(People._ID, "1");
    valuse.put(People.NAME, "name");
    Uri uri = mResolver.insert(People.CONTENT_URI, valuse);
}
...
```

The problem here is it's returning **Rowcount = 0** in the logs and giving the following exception:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Please help me to resolve this issue, why it's showing no rows?